# Image overlay with pseudo class in tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, overlay, pseudo-element

I am trying to add image overlay of static color using `tailwindcss`. If you inspect the browser the parent div is taking the size of the image only, so ideally the `before` pseudoclass should take the parent's height and width if I use `w-full` or `h-full`. Since it's also child of the `div`. But that is not the case.

I tried it with only css thinking I might be making mistake in tailwindcss (Since I just started using it) but the result was the same.

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="iniline before:content-{} before: inline before:absolute before:left-0 before:right-0 before:top-0 before:z-10 before:h-full before:w-full before:bg-fuchsia-600 before:opacity-30">
  <img src="//unsplash.it/201" alt="Image" class="relative z-0" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider making the `<div>` a position parent by applying `position: relative` via the `relative` class. To "shrink-wrap" the width to the image, you could apply `width: max-content` to the `<div>` via `w-max`.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="relative w-max before:absolute before:left-0 before:right-0 before:top-0 before:z-10 before:h-full before:w-full before:bg-fuchsia-600 before:opacity-30">
  <img src="//unsplash.it/201" alt="Image" class="relative z-0" />
</div>
```